# Can't login as sysdba in oracle sqlplus

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, sysdba

'hello

I am trying to login  locally installed oracle 11g database from my windows machine using

```
system / as sysdba
```

Its asking for username and password , but In my knowledge its using default windows account and will login without any prompt . why its prompting here and the current account is indeed a memeber of oradba group .

2) I tried to connect using

`conn /as sysdba`

its logging inside sqlplus without any prompt

Whats happening in both cases , can someone give me a quick heads up ?

thanks

**Update 1**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

connecting by 
`$ sqlplus / as sysdba` or `SQL> conn / as sysdba` mean connecting to the SYS schema implicitly.

That's the most privileged schema of Oracle, and because of this the Operating System of the machine where Oracle installed, trusts and accepts the main administration schema and no needs a password and a username.

Comment: while connecting with sysdba with password why its prompting for username and password

Comment: check my screenshot above

Comment: @coffemug Did you start your listener or start up DB?

Comment: its running and i have two instance , do i need to make specific about the sid while connecting to sqlplus

Comment: Yes, you need to set your SID such as `C:\Users\...> set ORACLE_SID=SID1` before connecting. OR SID1 may be replaced with the second one namely SID2.

Comment: @coffemug we already do not need to express username(sys) or that's password(Oracle already trusts the current OS) or dbname(it's already defined in tnsnames.ora in this filesystem), we only need to express which instance should be chosen.

Comment: what about the `set oracle_sid `, does it required to connect to the database

Comment: @coffemug yes, that's required even if the DB is of single instance.

Answer (score 1):

On windows for / AS SYSDBA you need

- the user to be part of the dba group, check using NET USERS YOUR_NAME_HERE
- sqlnet.ora contains the line SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
- the dos session is started "AS ADMINISTRATOR"

The last one catches me out all the time.

Comment: I was missing the (NTS)

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the same creating sqlnet.ora in the below file location as follows, and it worked. hope this helps!

file location: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/network/admin

vi sqlnet.ora

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(ezconnect)

Comment: this environment is on Oracle Linux Server release 7.9
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9"

Answer (score 0):

Enter Usaername : sys / as sysdba

Enter Password : sys

You will be connected